# Jquery UI Combobox and DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm having problems with Jquery Jquery UI Combobox & asp.net

1. The DropDown is not working or render
2. JavaScript error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined" 'input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item)'`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       (function ($) {
           $.widget("ui.combobox", {
               _create: function () {
                   var input,
         that = this,
         wasOpen = false,
         select = this.element.hide(),
         selected = select.children(":selected"),
         value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
         wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>")
           .addClass("ui-combobox")
           .insertAfter(select);

                   function removeIfInvalid(element) {
                       var value = $(element).val(),
           matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(value) + "$", "i"),
           valid = false;
                       select.children("option").each(function () {
                           if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                               this.selected = valid = true;
                               return false;
                           }
                       });

                       if (!valid) {
                           // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                           $(element)
             .val("")
             .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
             .tooltip("open");
                           select.val("");
                           setTimeout(function () {
                               input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                           }, 2500);
                           input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
                       }
                   }

                   input = $("<input>")
         .appendTo(wrapper)
         .val(value)
         .attr("title", "")
         .addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input")
         .autocomplete({
             delay: 0,
             minLength: 0,
             source: function (request, response) {
                 var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                 response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                     var text = $(this).text();
                     if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                         return {
                             label: text.replace(
                     new RegExp(
                       "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                       $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                       ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                     ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                             value: text,
                             option: this
                         };
                 }));
             },
             select: function (event, ui) {
                 ui.item.option.selected = true;
                 that._trigger("selected", event, {
                     item: ui.item.option
                 });
             },
             change: function (event, ui) {
                 if (!ui.item) {
                     removeIfInvalid(this);
                 }
             }
         })
         .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

                   input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                       return $("<li>")
           .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
           .appendTo(ul);
                   };

                   $("<a>")
         .attr("tabIndex", -1)
         .attr("title", "Show All Items")
         .tooltip()
         .appendTo(wrapper)
         .button({
             icons: {
                 primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
             },
             text: false
         })
         .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
         .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
         .mousedown(function () {
             wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
         })
         .click(function () {
             input.focus();

             // close if already visible
             if (wasOpen) {
                 return;
             }

             // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
             input.autocomplete("search", "");
         });

                   input.tooltip({
                       tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                   });
               },

               _destroy: function () {
                   this.wrapper.remove();
                   this.element.show();
               }
           });
       })(jQuery);

       $(function () {
           $("#ddl_company").combobox();
           $("#toggle").click(function () {
               $("#ddl_company").toggle();
           });
       });
   ```

Comment: `data()` probably returns a string, are you sure you can use the `_renderItem` method on that string ?

Comment: I copied the code form the example

Answer (score 1):

`ui-autocomplete` key is only available from JQueryUI 1.10, try `autocomplete` instead